# Installing maven and maven plugins

Tags: java, maven

I have downloaded Apache Maven 3.1.1 on windows xp and the installation works.However,i want to start jetty but i am thinking there is a way i have to tell maven where to find jetty first but i went ahead anyway and i got this

```
C:\maven>mvn jetty:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadat
a.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata
.xml (22 KB at 3.2 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-m
etadata.xml (13 KB at 1.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20.339s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 23 10:17:40 EAT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/13M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plu
gin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repo
sitories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\Karl Meiwes\.m2\repository), central
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundF
orPrefixException
C:\maven>
```

Will i have to tell maven where to find jetty and how do i install the jetty plugin?.In this version of maven,i find the plugins directory.Should there be one?.

Comment: Maven resolves all the plugins you need through the POM structure. The basic ones like dependency management and regular Java compiling are built into the "super POM" (the root parent project); specialized ones like Jetty just need to be added to the POM for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the plug-in to your pom.xml .  [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html)'s the documentation.

Comment: I agree the name is confusing, but it has nothing to do with the Eclipse IDE.  [In 2009 the project was moved to the Eclipse Foundation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
</plugin>
```